# Trigonometric Theorem Proof: If $\sin x = \sin y$, then, $x = n\pi + (-1)^ny.$

Tags: trigonometry

I am working on trigonometric theorems from this [book](http://epathshala.nic.in/wp-content/doc/book/flipbook/Class%20XI/11076Mathematics/Chapter_3/docs/Chapter_3.pdf). I am referring to Theorem $1$ on page $75$. I am not able to understand how final conclusion is derived from second last step. I am not able to derive the highlighted part from the $2$ equations above it.

[image]

Comment: Every integer must be either odd or even ...

Comment: I see that now. Thanks.

Comment: Please post as an answer so that I can mark it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you combine $x=2n\pi$ with $x=(2n+1)\pi$, you get $x=n\pi$ for all $n\in\textbf{Z}=\{2n+1\}\cup \{2n\}$

Likewise  $(-1)^{2n+1}$ and $(-1)^{2n}$ combine to give $(-1)^n$ for all $n\in\textbf{Z}$ which gives the result. Combination here means union.

The solution $x=n\pi+(-1)^n y$, $n\in\textbf{Z}$, gives all the possible values from $x=2n\pi+(-1)^{2n}$ and $x=(2n+1)\pi+(-1)^{2n+1}$