# Proving $\frac{1}{2}=1$ using inverse trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, fake-proofs

Let $\theta=\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$
We know,$\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin \theta$
or,
$$\sin(\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2})=\sin(\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2})$$
or,
$$\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}=\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$$
or
$$2\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}=\pi$$
or $$\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{2}=\sin \frac{\pi}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{2}=1$$
I don't understand what's wrong with the argument.I know I messed up the principal values but can't yet find the error.

Comment: The error is just after your second or. if $\sin a = \sin b $ then $ a=b+2k\pi or a = \pi-b +2k\pi $

Comment: But if the domain of $\sin$ is from $-\frac{\pi}{2} to \frac{\pi}{2}$,then isn't it okay to cancel the values?

Comment: $\sin x=\sin y$ does not mean $x=y.$ You've just used a theorem that proves that, since $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi -x).$

Comment: @a_i_r but $ \pi -\sin^{-1}1/2$ is in $[\pi/2 ,3\pi/2]$

Comment: Yeah, if $x$ is in that range, then $\pi-x$ is not in that range, except for $x=\pi/2,$ and then it is true that $\pi -\pi/2=\pi/2.$

Comment: hama_Andallah could u please show how you deduced $\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac{1}{2}$ is in that range?

Comment: @a_i_r  $\pi-\sin^{-1}\frac 12=\pi- \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{5\pi}{6}$

Comment: If $x<\frac{\pi}2,$ then $\pi -x >\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Comment: @a_i_r To be clear, if you're confused about the answers there is an error in the statement $\sin(x)=\sin(y)\therefore x=y$. In your case, although we know $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin(\theta)$, do note that $\pi-\theta\neq\theta$ unless $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

It is true that if $x,y\in\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ and $\sin(x)=\sin(y),$ then $x=y.$

It is also true that $\sin(\pi -x)=\sin(x)$ for any $x.$

These two together show, with your argument, that if $x$ and $\pi-x$ are both in the range $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$ then $x=\frac\pi2.$

But if $x<\frac{\pi}{2}.$ then $\pi-x>\frac{\pi}{2}.$ So this is not as big a result as one might initially think.

Answer (score 0):

The principal solution to $\theta=\sin^{-1}(\frac 12)$ is $\theta=\frac\pi 6$

Note that $\pi-\frac\pi 6=\frac{5\pi}{6}\neq \frac \pi 6$ (while $\sin(\frac{5\pi}{6})=\frac12$ still holds)

Indeed, the quality $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$ *defines* an injective, or one-to-one, function, which $\sin$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that $\require{cancel} \sin x=\sin y \implies x \cancel= y$ . [This might be of some use](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2114873). Take for example $ \sin 135 = \sin 405$ but here $135\cancel=405$.