# $\sin x=\sin y$ mis-understanding

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$\arcsin(x)$ is the inverse function of $\sin(x)$, this means that:
$$\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$$
If I want to solve the equation:
$$\sin(x)=\sin(y)$$
using this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2114873/trigonometric-theorem-proof-if-sin-x-sin-y-then-x-n-pi-1ny), $x=\pi - y$ for instance.
but, also we can say that:
$$x=\arcsin(\sin x)=\arcsin(\sin y)=y$$
which is for me a contradiction. Where is the missing point in my writings?

Comment: The identity $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$ holds only when $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. If $x$ is in that range, then $y=\pi-x$ will not be. Neither will $z=x+2\pi$ even though also $\sin z=\sin x$. In other words $\sin x$ has no *global* inverse (that is one that would hold for all $x$). Periodicity alone would make that impossible.

Comment: $\arcsin$ is only the inverse of $\sin$ in a suitably restricted domain. Read the section *"Principal values"* in the following [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values).

Comment: And, if $x=3,$ you can't just write that $x=\sin(\arcsin x),$ either.

Comment: $\sin x$ is not one-to-one fuction, is many-to-one, then there are no inverse function for whole domain of $\sin x$. That's why inverse function covers only part of domain of $\sin x$, exactly $[-\pi/2;\pi/2]$. That's why $x=\arcsin \sin(x)$ is correct only for this part of domain of $\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WHat's wrong is your very first sentence. The function $\sin:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ DOES NOT have an inverse. It is a periodic function, so not injective (one-to-one) so definitely cannot be inverted.

On the other hand, if you **restrict** the domain and target, you get $\sin|_{[-\pi/2,\pi/2]}:[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\to [-1,1]$. This restricted function (which is different from the usual $\sin$, since we changed the domain and target) is invertible, and it's inverse is called $\arcsin:[-1,1]\to [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$. So,
\begin{align}
\arcsin:= \left(\sin|_{[-\pi/2,\pi/2]}\right)^{-1}.
\end{align}

---

Some remarks: we can restrict the $\sin$ function to other intervals and still get invertible functions. FOr example, $\sin|_{[5\pi/2,7\pi/2]}:[5\pi/2,7\pi/2]\to[-1,1]$ is also invertible, **but** its inverse function is NOT $\arcsin$, it is $\arcsin +2\pi$. There are actually infinitely many other intervals we can restrict to and get an invertible function, and it turns out the inverses differ by multiples of $\pi$

The name $\arcsin$, rather than $\sin^{-1}$ is thus appropriate. The function $\sin$ is not invertible, and $\arcsin$ refers to the inverse of a very specific restriction of $\sin$. Also, it is purely convention that we define $\arcsin$ by restricting $\sin$ to $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, the so-called *principal branch*.